# How to use make and compile as C99?

Tags: linux, makefile, c99, c89, kbuild

I'm trying to compile a linux kernel module using a Makefile:

```
obj-m += main.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Which gives me:

```
main.c:54: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
```

I need to switch to C99.  After reading I noticed I need to add a flag -std=c99, not sure where it suppose to be added.

How do I change the Makefile so it will compile as C99?

Comment: I thought C99 was a exploit script for PHP hehe

Comment: [How to compile a Linux kernel module using -std=gnu99?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910064/how-to-compile-a-linux-kernel-module-using-std-gnu99)

Answer (score -8, accepted):

It's got nothing to do with the makefile. ISO C90 forbids declaring variables anywhere but in the beginning of a block or the file - like this

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   int a; /* Ok */
   int b = 3; /* Ok */

   printf("Hello, the magic number is %d!\n", b);
   int c = 42; /* ERROR! Can only declare variables in the beginning of the block */
   printf("I also like %d.. but not as much as %d!\n", c, b);

   return 0;
}
```

Thus it has to be modified to this...

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   int a; /* Ok */
   int b = 3; /* Ok */
   int c = 42; /* Ok! */

   printf("Hello, the magic number is %d!\n", b);
   printf("I also like %d.. but not as much as %d!\n", c, b);

   return 0;
}
```

You can only "fix" that in the source code, not in the makefile.

This rule has been relaxed in C99, but in my opinion it's a good idea to separate variable definitions, declarations and initializations from the code below it :)

So to change your makefile to make it compile with C99, you need to change the Makefile in the "build" directory that your makefile is referencing, and add the "-std=c99" at the "gcc" line compiling the source file.

Comment: CFLAGS is much more common, preferred, and less fragile than editing each invocation of the compiler.

Comment: After living in the OO (Java) world for a long time and recently getting back into using C on a more day to day basis I have to disagree with the point about separating variable information out. Keeping things in as small a scope as possible seems more important. Some variables will only be needed inside of a while or for loop for example.

Comment: @powerj1984  You may use brace {} scoping in this case.  LukeN is correct as in *what would be accepted by the kernel main line*.  Whether that is a good thing all around, I won't say and I guess it is not what the OP asked.

Comment: The kernel allows c11 now, then no need to stay with this old pedantic style.

Answer (score 23):

The correct way to add compiler flags when compiling modules is by setting the `ccflags-y` variable. Like this:

```
ccflags-y := -std=gnu99
```

See [Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt#L286) in the kernel tree for more information.

Note that I'm using the `gnu99` standard instead of `c99` since the Linux kernel heavily relies on GNU extensions.

Comment: Hi, I add ccflags-y to the Makefile for my own module, but the compiler still warns that "ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code". Why?

Comment: @basicthinker: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15910064/how-to-compile-a-linux-kernel-module-using-std-gnu99) helps

Answer (score 20):

You could just add

```
CFLAGS=-std=c99
```

To the top of your `makefile`, or you can make the code compliant with C90 (as LukeN suggests.)