# How to compile a Linux kernel module using -std=gnu99?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel, c99

I've recently learned how to program simple character drivers and while playing around with the code I noticed that I get a lot of the following GCC warnings thrown for my C99 code:

```
warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
```

I assume this is because the main Linux kernel Makefile is set to compile using a non-C99 standard. I searched around I found this answer here on stackoverflow: [How to use make and compile as C99?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935047/how-to-use-make-and-compile-as-c99/5543589#5543589)

So I naturally tried the following in my Makefile:

```
ccflags-y := -std=gnu99
```

Unfortunately this didn't silence the GCC warnings. I checked the verbose output of `make` and verified that GCC is indeed executed with the `-std=gnu99` tacked on at the end; so I'm a bit confused.

How do I properly compile a Linux kernel module using the `-std=gnu99` option?

**EDIT**:

I noticed the GCC output shows this option: `-Wdeclaration-after-statement`. Is this why I am getting the warnings even with the `-std=gnu99` option?

Comment: The linux makefile is intially called before your module, so GCC might get mixed std= definitions.

Comment: Why don't you just declare all the variables at the beginning of the function and get rid of the warning that way?

Comment: This is probably because that feature of C99 (declaration after statement) is one of the things that Linus seems to hate. So the linux coding style forbids this.

Comment: @JensGustedt That's odd, I vaguely remember that being mention in the [Linux kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) document, but I can't seem to find it anymore.

Comment: [dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935047/how-to-use-make-and-compile-as-c99)? you do however have a better possible answer.

Comment: @Gonzalo you'd be out of luck trying to do it when you want to make a constant at the right time, like `const int numTimesFooDone=doFoo();`. You'll have to leave `numTimesFooDone` non-`const` and risk mistakenly overwriting it without noticing somewhere later, e.g. `if(numTimesFooDone=3)...`. This just takes away some useful compiler help from the programmer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It turns out that `-std=gnu99` *does* in fact work; I began seeing errors regarding C99 features after removing the compiler flag. So that meant something else was causing the warnings to print out besides the `-std=` option.

After parsing through the verbose output via `make V=1`, I discovered the `-Wdeclaration-after-statement` option as part of the GCC execution. This was the cause of the ISO C90 mixed declaration warnings I saw.

To disable the ISO C90 warnings, pass this to GCC: `-Wno-declaration-after-statement`.

For example:

```
ccflags-y := -std=gnu99 -Wno-declaration-after-statement
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the flag in your *Makefile*, if you have one:

```
FLAGS=-std=gnu99
```